# Disable the Opentsdb .out file in Log Directory( /var/log/opentsdb/hostname.out )

Tags: time-series, opentsdb

The file **" /var/log/opentsdb/hostname.out"** consuming very large disk usage and producing the file size in GB. Also let me know how these metrics are recorded in the hostname.out file in log directory.

If possible please let me know the steps to disable the /var/log/opentsdb/hostname.out file and my disk space is always filling up.

Eg : [root@tsdb-host2 opentsdb]# du -sh opentsdb-tsdb-host2.server.local-opentsdb.out
3.4G    opentsdb-tsdb-host2.server.local-opentsdb.out

Note ; I have cleared now and it was above 50 GB.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this same problem we modified the following line in the start script /etc/init.d/opentsdb

```
daemon --user $USER --pidfile $PID_FILE "$PROG $PROG_OPTS 1>> ${LOG_FILE}opentsdb.out 2>> ${LOG_FILE}opentsdb.err &"
```

changed it to:

```
daemon --user $USER --pidfile $PID_FILE "$PROG $PROG_OPTS 1>> /dev/null 2>> ${LOG_FILE}opentsdb.err &"
```

to redirect the stdout to /dev/null since logback is taking care of the actual file logging and it stopped writing to the out file but continued to log the same messages to the rolled logfile

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: this is the solution we used to solve the same problem